# How can I edit wordpress theme core file as a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, editor

I recently have a wordpress project for a friend, I'm building the blog on a wordpress theme called  **MagazineNP** parent theme.
I've been actually trying to remove it's footer credits but I could edit it from the parent theme succefully, when i try editing it as a child theme, the changes do not reflect on the site.

I later discovered that core file are not easily edited cause this file I'm editing is found in the theme's core folder.

I'll appreciate any help on how to do this in my child theme i.e editing the core file adding it to my child theme so it wont be overiden when updated.

Comment: It depends on how the parent theme is build, and what you want to modify. if build correctly the parent theme will use functions as `get_template_part` to load parts of the template. in your case I would start looking at the footer.php file and see if they use extra template files in there or if they directly echo the credits in there. if they use `get_template_part` to load subfiles, you can copy that file to the child theme remaining the same directory structure, if they do not you can try copying footer.php to the child theme and modify that.

Comment: For more info on get_template_parts I recommend looking at this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

Comment: Another thing you can try if this text comes from a function defined inside a core file. Are they testing said function already exists in that file, is to create a copy of said function in the child themes functions.php to overwirte the function with your own code

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
To get my request better I will send the codes:
In the parent theme, I could edit the footer from the following path: parent-theme folder>core>template-funtions.php

When I edit it from the parent theme, It worked fine and showed the results on my blog BUT when I copied it into the child theme i.e child-theme>core>template-functions.php it wont show any changes.

Comment: that file `template-funtions.php` can not be overwritten directly, however the functions inside there may be. If they are defined with an `if` statement around it. so for example if your function is called `print_footer_copy` look for an if statement that looks is follows `if(!function_exists('print_footer_copy'))` . If this is the case go into your child theme and place a copy of that function inside `functions.php`. if there is no if statement like `if(!function_exists('function_name_here'))`, placing it in functions.php will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks for this enlightenment here's the code from the template-funtions.php file that pertains to the footer only (not the full code but it is responsible for what happens in the footer)

Comment: <pre>function magazinenp_author_link()
{
 return sprintf(
  esc_html__('Theme by %s', 'magazinenp'),
  '<a href="' . esc_url('https://mantrabrain.com') . '" target="_blank" title="' . esc_attr__('Mantrabrain', 'magazinenp') . '" >' . esc_html__('Mantrabrain', 'magazinenp') . '</a>'
 );
} </pre>

Comment: the line of code before this function does it say something like `if(!function_exists('magazinenp_author_link'))` ? if so you can overwrite the function if not  it cant be overwritten in the child theme